# Вычесть из даты 5 минут

Tags: php

Как вычесть из даты получаемой date('c') 5 минут?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто, используйте `strtotime()`:

```
echo date('c', strtotime('-5 minutes'));
```